# Could not bind on a random free port error while trying to connect to spark master

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, pyspark

I have a spark master running on amazon ec2.
I tried to connect to it using pyspark as follows from another ec2 instance as follows:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
                            .master("spark_url_as_obtained_in_web_ui") \
                            .getOrCreate()
```

The following were the errors:

> To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
>
> 2018-04-04 20:03:04 WARN  Utils:66 - Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
>
> ............
>
> java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (on a random free port)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate binding address for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.driver.bindAddress for SparkDriver) to the correct binding address.

I tried all the solutions as described here but to no avail:

1. [Connecting to a remote Spark master - Java / Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42048475/connecting-to-a-remote-spark-master-java-scala)
2. [All masters are unresponsive ! ? Spark master is not responding with datastax architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782800/all-masters-are-unresponsive-spark-master-is-not-responding-with-datastax-ar)
3. [Spark Standalone Cluster - Slave not connecting to Master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31166851/spark-standalone-cluster-slave-not-connecting-to-master/32187873)
4. [Spark master-machine:7077 not reachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557223/spark-master-machine7077-not-reachable)
5. [spark submit "Service 'Driver' could not bind on port" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38429333/spark-submit-service-driver-could-not-bind-on-port-error)
6. https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/8257/how-can-i-resolve-it.html

What could be going wrong??

Comment: When I got that message, I had to update /etc/hosts to match changed DHCP address (in development cluster after power outage).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Set `spark.driver.bindAddress` to your local IP like `127.0.0.1`.

```
pyspark -c spark.driver.bindAddress=127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 16):

While creating spark session set the below configurations

```
spark =SparkSession.builder.appName(str(name))\
      .master("local[*]").config("spark.driver.memory","5g")\
      .config("spark.driver.host","10.51.4.110")\ #Machine ip
      .config("spark.driver.bindAddress","10.51.4.110")\ #Machine ip
      .getOrCreate()
```

Sometimes In addition to bind address, we need to set the host address also. In my case system host address changed to system name. Spark shows timeout error. then after setting host and bind address as same. It works fine

*10.51.4.110 - Local Machine IP

Comment: Worked for me with just adding 
.config("spark.driver.host", "127.0.0.1") \
.config("spark.driver.bindAddress", "127.0.0.1")

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar issue on Windows 10 recently.

Resolved it by following below steps:

- Fixed it by setting a user environment variable SPARK_LOCAL_IP = 127.0.0.1
- Restart the command line as an admin

Answer (score 2):

On a MacOS, with a standalone spark cluster, setting `SPARK_MASTER_HOST` to 'localhost' instead of '127.0.0.1' solved to problem for me.

`export SPARK_MASTER_HOST='localhost'`

Comment: Please note that it is for a Spark Standalone cluster not a Spark application. They're two different "beasts".